# Rename a column name in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm using following pvf and i want to rename the salesamount to "Sales Amount" so in pivot table header it will show Sales Amount instead of salesamount, please advise.

```
Set pvf = gWO.AddDataField(pvt, salesamount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this snippet:

```vb
Sub AddMoreFields() 
 
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")             'Change for your PivotTable name
 .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _ 
 "PivotTable1").PivotFields("salesamount"), "Sales Amount"    
 End With 
 
End Sub
```